# How to round an image automatically in Portrait and Landscape?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nslayoutconstraint

I have a UIImageView of 100*100 which I am rounding in a circle shape using below code:

```
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.width/2
```

There is a constraint added to this imageView with aspect ratio to superview. This is because I need to change the imageView size accordingly as the superview size changes.

**Problem:**
When I rotate the view in landscape mode, the imageView is resized but it doesn't gets rounded. I have added screenshots for it.

How/Where should I make it rounded again. Should I register to a notification and then set the rounding again. As the imageView size has changed. Is there anything that auto-layout could manage itself.

Please give a good solution.

[image: In portriat mode]
[image: In Landscape mode]

**Edit:**

Here is the imageView Constraint

[image]

Comment: Can you tell the constraint of your imageView

Comment: Added imageView constraints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this In you ViewController

```
 - (void)layoutSubviews
 {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    NSLog(@"%f", imageView.frame.size.width/2);

    layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.width/2;
 }
```

Comment: Should I implement this in UIImageView subclass or in UIViewController?

Comment: Answer has been Edited ;)

Comment: Right, an alternative is to try the same code inside `- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Answer (score 2):

You can update the `cornerRadius` of the imageView in `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` method:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.bounds.size.width / 2;
}
```

This will be called only when the screen rotated to a new orientation if the view controller supports the new orientation.

---

Or update its `cornerRadius` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.bounds.size.width / 2;
}
```

You should regardless of how many times the method executed. It will always keep the correct result at the time.

Answer (score 0):

Use this when landscape mode

```
[imageView layoutIfNeeded];
```

then

```
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.width/2
```

Comment: Where should I write these 2 lines? In which method?

Comment: [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self     selector:@selector(orientationdidChange:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];

Comment: orientationdidChange method then put this code into this method

Comment: Is there any other method without implementing notifications. Does Auto layout automatically doesn't update this?

Comment: If you have any method that are calling after rotating your iphone then put this code in that method

Comment: Its compulsory to call this code [imageView layoutIfNeeded]; other wise you will get old frame size